# C++ std::thread. Как обратить и завершить поток

Tags: c++, многопоточность

Всем привет,

Как обратиться к потоку по **id** и попросить его "завершиться"?

Использую стандарт С++11 и библиотеку `<thread>`

Спасибо)

Comment: попросить его "завершиться"? под этим вы подразумеваете убить поток или передать сигнал потому, чтобы он по скорее выполнил функцию?

Comment: "завершиться" - убить поток)

Comment: Нельзя убивать потоки просто так, они могут владеть некоторыми глобальными ресурсами и просто не успеют их освободить

Comment: Да это не безопасно, и в C++11 такой функции нет. Вам необходимо процедуру быстрого завершения потока реализовать самому.

Comment: Можете подсказать как это реализовать?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Никак. `std::thread` такое не предусматривает.

Используйте `atomic<bool>`, `[shared_]future<void>::wait_for` или другие примитивы чтобы просигнализировать коду внутри потока о том что он должен завершиться.